# Different metafile rendering on Win8.1 and Win7

Tags: fonts, windows-8.1, gdi+, gdi, system.drawing

[Solution to reproduce](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6D7BF9F1F673B509%21912)

I am using following code to draw a metafile:
{

```
<DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="CopyEnhMetaFileA", BestFitMapping:=False, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True, _
   SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function CopyEnhMetaFile(ByVal hemfSrc As IntPtr, ByVal lpszFile As String) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="DeleteEnhMetaFile", _
   SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function DeleteEnhMetaFile(ByVal hemfSrc As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Private Sub DrawArialTest()
    Dim TestString = "11111111111112"
    Dim metafileStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim offScreenDC = Graphics.FromHwndInternal(IntPtr.Zero)
    Dim myImagePointer = offScreenDC.GetHdc()
    Dim Image = New Metafile(metafileStream, myImagePointer, EmfType.EmfPlusDual)

    ' Create the graphics object
    Using g = Walker.GraphicsUtilities.GdiGraphics.FromImage(Image)
        SetGraphicsSettings(g)
        Try
            ' Draw in the metafile
            Dim sFormat = New StringFormat
            sFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces
            Dim Y = 0
            For intI As Single = 0 To 30
                Using font = New Font("Arial", 6 + intI, FontStyle.Regular)
                    Dim size = g.MeasureString(TestString, font, PointF.Empty, sFormat)
                    Dim rec = New RectangleF(0, Y, size.Width, size.Height)
                    g.DrawString(TestString, font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, rec, sFormat)
                    g.DrawRectangles(Pens.Red, New RectangleF() {rec})
                    Y += rec.Height
                End Using

            Next
            sFormat.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
    SaveEnhMetafile(Image, "c:\temp\test.emf")
End Sub

Public Shared Function SaveEnhMetafile(ByVal sourceMetafile As Metafile, ByVal fileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim hEMF As IntPtr = DirectCast(sourceMetafile.Clone, Metafile).GetHenhmetafile()
    If Not hEMF.Equals(New IntPtr(0)) Then
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then Kill(fileName)
        DeleteEnhMetaFile(CopyEnhMetaFile(hEMF, fileName))
        DeleteEnhMetaFile(hEMF)
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
Sub SetGraphicsSettings(ByVal g As IGraphics)
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.GammaCorrected
    'g.TextRenderingHint = Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
    g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
End Sub
```

}

If I then open the metafile from this test I see following:

Win8.1 64bit

[image: Win8.1 64bit]

Win7 64bit

[image: Win7 64bit]

I was not able to reproduce this error with any other fonts but Arial.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

[Link to metafile](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6D7BF9F1F673B509!894&authkey=!ANxuDkjcRXpbHXU&ithint=file%2Cemf)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is interested here is what I got from Microsoft:

Posted by Microsoft on 5/22/2015 at 1:39 PM
Hello! Thank you for your feedback. This is a bug in GDIPlus API GdipMeasureString, rather than in Graphics.MeasureString. I'm sorry you had been misdirected to this forum. I had opened an internal bug for the GDI+ team, they will investigate and triage it. Since this bug is external to the Dot Net Framework, I'm resolving it as such. 
Thanks,
The Windows Forms Team